# Setting A Limit On Input Field Creation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, field

I haven't found nothing on this topic so I though I quickly ask here.

Anyway I am creating a feature which allow users to add new admins to there clan and to make it easier the user can add a new input field that is all working fine ;)

But what I want is to only allow the user to add a maxim of 5 admins at one time to save server resources as at the moment they can have as many as they want.

How could I archive this?

(The code is below)

```
<form>
    <input type="text" />
</form>
<button id="addFields">Add another field
    </button>
```

---

```
   //JQUERY SIDE BELOW

$(function ($) {

    $('body').on("click", '#addFields', function () {
        $('form').append('<input type="text" />')
    })

})(jQuery)
```

Comment: I will be adding server side to limit this using the client side would be less hassle so they don't have to submit the form then get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Vote to Close said is right, you'll need to stop this on both the server and client side.  On the client side, you could do this:

```
$(function ($) {
    var MAX_LIMIT = 5;
    $('body').on("click", '#addFields', function () {
        if ($("form > input[type='text']").length < MAX_LIMIT) {
            $('form').append('<input type="text" />');
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

client side you can do in this way

```
$(function ($) {
       $('body').on("click", '#addFields', function () {
        if ($("form > input:text").length < 5) {
            $('form').append('<input type="text" />');
        }
        else{
         alert('can't add more admins');
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

but in this way you are blocking only to add maximum 5 admins at the same time.

in your server side you should do something like this (a more robust solution) (SQL)

```
    SET @admins= (SELECT COUNT(IdUSerAdmin) FROM Users where IdAdmin= @YouAdminUser)

    IF(@admins < 5)
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO USERS ....
    END
```

Comment: Thanks this worked ;) I will also add the server side in case they try to get around the client side method.
I also voted you up and accepted your solution

Comment: I should ask another quick question how can I display a message in jquery that states they carn't add anymore admins

Comment: @Spudster I'll answer as soon as possible

Comment: No problem ;) anytime

Comment: @Spudster I have updated my answer.. let me know if is ok for you. For any information I'm here.

Comment: Thanks ;) I let you know if it works hopefully not too long just quickly working on another part of the clan feature

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function ($) {
    var totalFieldsAdded = 0;
    var totalFieldsAllowed = 5;
    $('body').on("click", '#addFields', function () {
        if(totalFieldsAdded < totalFieldsAllowed){
            $('form').append('<input type="text" />');
            totalFieldsAdded++;
        }
    })

})(jQuery)
```

Comment: not really "urgent" but `totalFieldsAllowed` should be 4, since there is an input already on stage...

Comment: Thanks just relised that I fix this now ;)